# Textarea PHP post issue

Tags: php, html, post, textarea

I have a PHP post problem with a textarea.  I've searched this site, and the suggested remedies involved pulling the textarea's ID, and making sure you are using htmlspecialchars.  I'm doing both, and I still can't figure out why it won't post the contents of my textarea.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="email.php" name="contactform" id="contactform" class="form form-stacked c-form">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
<textarea name="theTextArea" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="submit btn outline" id="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
$realName = $name = $theMessage = $subject = $WHATmessage = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $realName = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $name = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $theMessage = test_input($_POST["theTextArea"]);
}
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

$subject = 'SUPERGROUP Inquiry - ' . $realName . ' - [' .date("F j, Y, g:i a").']';
$WHATmessage = $realName . ' is looking forward to hearing from us!'.PHP_EOL.'Their email is: '. $name .'!'.PHP_EOL.'They said: "'.$theMessage.'"';
mail('hello@sprgrp.com', $subject, $WHATmessage );
```

Comment: what is "test_input" for?  If you're looking for the value, you're not getting it.  You're getting the result of "test_input".

Comment: the test_input is just to run the data through htmlspecialchars.

Comment: Ah.  So "test_input" is a function that returns the cleaned string.  That makes sense.  So, what are you getting back out of that?  Or, have you tried it without that?

Comment: i have tried without it, and i still get back nothing.  var_dump($theMessage) just yields the blank string I set it to in the beginning.

Comment: Have you tried all of this with single quotes rather than the double quotes you have there?  PHP can be funny about that.

Comment: Well...  I'm posting that as the answer then!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comment as answer, as it appears to have worked.

Have you tried all of this with single quotes rather than the double quotes you have there? PHP can be funny about that.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things here....

"name" is a reserved word.  Do not use name as your name.

```
 <input name="name"
```

It's probably a core issue in most of your posting problems.

Instead, try

```
<input name="fullname"
```

Also, you want to "addslashes" on POST, not "stripslashes".  You remove after a db query to dsiplay the 'raw' source to the user.
That's mostly for database interactions, though.
For an email, it's basically unnecessary to do so.   The htmlspecialchars should take care of everything else.

Comment: I got the name already.  The name works.  I'll try addslashes and see if it works, thanks!

Comment: I changed the name to "fullname", reflected the changes in PHP and now i'm not getting that either.

Comment: You may want to try single quotes on your fields, $_POST['myfield']